# How do I place just one of my Mysqli bind results into an array to use the in_array() function for a match?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and I want to match an array from a prepared statement results on $Fid only.  How do I go about doing this with while($fr->fetch())?

```
$str = array(34353,34334,66667);

if($onlineFriends = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM FRIENDS_DIR WHERE ID=? AND ONLINE=1")){
$fr->bind_param('s', $dataA);
$fr->execute();
$fr->bind_result($Fuserid, $Fid);
$fr->store_result();
$frCount= $fr->num_rows > 0;
if($fr->num_rows > 0){
while($fr->fetch()){
$Fid;

}}}
```

Not sure how to fetch just $Fid into an array instead of all results so I can use the in_array() function to check.

```
if (in_array($Fid, $str, TRUE)){
$res = "match";
} else {
$res = "no match";
}
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `Fid` a field in the table?

Comment: yea but it is the bind result var not the name of the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question, something like this should work. Note that as Fid is an integer in your table, and you are generating your comparison values from `$_POST` data (hence it will be string values), you cannot use `strict` matching in `in_array`. So remove the third parameter to change that.

```
$res = "no match";
while ($fr->fetch()) {
    if (in_array($Fid, $str)){
        $res = "match";
        // do other stuff that you need to do on a match here
    }
    // do anything else with the query data here
}
echo $res;
```

Comment: This does get me closer I keep getting no match when all should match.  What would make it do this? Maybe the while statement?  Or is it trying to match the whole array against each result in the while loop array, maybe thats it?

Comment: @Jonny no it should only be attempting to match the current value of `$Fid` from the loop. I notice you have `SELECT *` in your query, perhaps that should be something like `SELECT user_id, id` so that the columns line up with your `bind_result` call?

Comment: Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given. this is the error i get which the id is an int so maybe move it outside the loop.  I place the $Fid in the second position of the in_array()

Comment: if (in_array($str, $Fid, TRUE)) this is how i tested it

Comment: @Jonny but that's not what I wrote in the answer, and is the wrong way round.

Comment: one array checked against another array does it matter?  Im not sure?  If so can you let me know how?  Ill do it the other way and check

Comment: it does matter i guess i keep getting no match on this though.  Swapping arrays did get rid of the error.  Ill play with it a bit and get back with you on it thanks for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186823/discussion-between-jonny-and-nick).